# Add subscription record to woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, subscriptions

I have installed woo-commerce subscriptions on my word-press site, integrating a payment gateway for checkout. The gateway is not supported by woo-commerce directly.

I have the checkout page and the payment processing page with code provided by the gateway to process the online payment.

I need to update the subscription status for the customer once his payment has gone through successfully via the gateway and the confirmation is received back.

Any pointers on how to update the subscription record in woocommerce subscriptions using a php code snippet would be very helpful.

I have searched around and found links on how to add a product in woocommerce, but not much on how to update or add a subscription record using a custom php snippet.

Comment: After some searching found a post that has the process:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202873/woocommerce-how-to-use-wc-create-order-with-subscription-product

Comment: The following code snippet worked for me after a few tweaks:                         1/ Create an insert an order                                                                                               2/ Create the subscription and insert it                                                                   3/ Activate subscriptions for the new order

Comment: Congratulations on finding out the answer yourself. If you post it here as an answer instead of a comment, and accept it, it will benefit the community (and may give you some reputation gain if people upvote it)

Comment: Thank you Hans, have posted the response. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create an order, then create a subscription, link the order to the subscription using woocommerce classes. A very helpful link found on SO outlines the steps:

[wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202873/](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/202873/)

The response given by Jeremy Warne worked for my website's logical flow.